# Как с помощью C# очистить корзину?

Tags: c#, .net

Как с помощью C# очистить корзину?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20172/Empty-the-Recycle-Bin-using-C

Answer (score 7):

Пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    enum RecycleFlags : uint
    {
        SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x00000001,
        SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI = 0x00000002,
        SHERB_NOSOUND = 0x00000004
    }

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern uint SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr hwnd, string pszRootPath, RecycleFlags dwFlags);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint result = SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, 0);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            // OK
        }
    }
}
```

Ссылка на источник: [How to programatically clear the recycle bin under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275731/5275890)